# Switch between Light/Dark modes according to time in Nuxt.js with Vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I have a dark theme set by default in `nuxt.config.js` `vuetify` settings, it's activated with `dark: false`. How can I activate it automatically during night hours ?

Comment: Write a little bit of js to check when is the night when it is not?

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed it this way:

```
  mounted() {
    this.setTheme()
  },
  methods: {
    setTheme() {
      const today = new Date()
      today.getHours() < 8 || today.getHours() > 20
        ? (this.$vuetify.theme.isDark = true)
        : (this.$vuetify.theme.isDark = false)
    }
  }
```